# How would I repeat each row in a Scala dataframe N times

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is the before of the dataframe:

[image]

and here is the after:

[image]

notice how the rows that are repeated are all next to each other, as opposed to just starting the dataframe over from scratch at the end.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`array_repeat`** with **`struct`** function then **explode** the array.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
/*
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   4|
|   2|   5|
|   3|   6|
+----+----+
*/
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

df.withColumn("arr",explode(array_repeat(struct(df.columns.head,df.columns.tail:_*),7))).
select("arr.*").
toDF("col1","col2").
show(100,false)
/*
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|1   |4   |
|1   |4   |
|1   |4   |
|1   |4   |
|1   |4   |
|1   |4   |
|1   |4   |
|2   |5   |
|2   |5   |
|2   |5   |
|2   |5   |
|2   |5   |
|2   |5   |
|2   |5   |
|3   |6   |
|3   |6   |
|3   |6   |
|3   |6   |
|3   |6   |
|3   |6   |
|3   |6   |
+----+----+
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting this errror:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: syntax error in attribute name: `;

Sorry I'm brand new to spark. What could this error be?

Comment: Not sure.. could you update the question with the code you are running.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function which duplicates a `DataFrame`:

```
def repeatRows(df: DataFrame, numRepeats: Int): DataFrame = {
    (1 until numRepeats).foldLeft(df)((growingDF, _) => growingDF.union(df))
}
```

The problem of having the resulting `DataFrame` sorted is separate from the duplication process, and hence wasn't included in the function, but can be easily achieved afterwards.

So let's take your problem:

```
// Problem setup
val someDF = Seq((1,4),(2,4),(3,6)).toDF("col1","col2")

// Duplicate followed by sort
val duplicatedSortedDF = repeatRows(someDF, 3).sort("col1")

// Show result
duplicatedSortedDF.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   4|
|   1|   4|
|   1|   4|
|   2|   4|
|   2|   4|
|   2|   4|
|   3|   6|
|   3|   6|
|   3|   6|
+----+----+
```

And there you have it.